# C# MVC Change Chart/Graph based on Dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, graph, visual-studio-2013, html-select

I'm trying to create a simple graph project in which the user selects a graph from drop down and the resulting graph is then loaded. Currently my graph loads but falls over to the default section of the switch, as expected as the user hasn't made a selection. when the user selects "Graph 1" and clicks submit nothing really happens the address now shows

```
http://localhost:51493/GraphDropdownModels?searchGraph=Graph+1
```

but the graph stays the same?

I also tried calling the Chart() in the case statement:

```
            switch (searchGraph)
        {
            case "Graph 1":
                graphselected = "1";
                Chart()
                break;
            case "Graph 2":
                graphselected = "2";
                Chart()
                break;
            case "Graph 3":
                graphselected = "3";
                Chart()
                break;
            case "Graph 4":
                graphselected = "4";
                Chart()
                break;
        }
```

However this seams to loop through but the graph-image never gets drawn.

Could anyone point me towards a solution ?

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestSolution.Models.GraphDropdownModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GraphDropdownModels", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    Graph: @Html.DropDownList("searchGraph", "Graph 1")
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
</p>
}
@*Render chart here*@
@{ Html.RenderAction("Chart");}
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GraphName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GraphName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.GraphID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.GraphID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.GraphID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

GraphDropdownModelControler.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using TestSolution.Models;

namespace TestSolution.Controllers
{
public class GraphDropdownModelsController : Controller
{
    private GraphingDBContext db = new GraphingDBContext();
    private string graphselected = "Graph 1";


    // GET: GraphDropdownModels
    public ActionResult Index(string searchGraph)
    {
        string item1 = "Graph 1";
        string item2 = "Graph 2";
        string item3 = "Graph 3";
        string item4 = "Graph 4";
        var GraphLst = new List<string> { item1, item2, item3, item4 };
        ViewBag.searchGraph = new SelectList(GraphLst);

        switch (searchGraph)
        {
            case "Graph 1":
                graphselected = "1";
                break;
            case "Graph 2":
                graphselected = "2";
                break;
            case "Graph 3":
                graphselected = "3";
                break;
            case "Graph 4":
                graphselected = "4";
                break;
        }

        return View(db.GraphNames.ToList());
    }
    public ActionResult Chart()
    {
        var chart = buildChart();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.Append(getChartImage(chart));
        result.Append(chart.GetHtmlImageMap("ImageMap"));
        return Content(result.ToString());
    }

    private Chart buildChart()
    {
        // Build Chart
        var chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 800;
        chart.Height = 600;

        // Create chart here
        chart.Titles.Add(CreateTitle());
        chart.Legends.Add(CreateLegend());
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(CreateChartArea());
        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries());

        return chart;
    }

    private string getChartImage(Chart chart)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string img = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,{0}' alt='' usemap='#ImageMap'>";
            chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
            return String.Format(img, encoded);
        }
    }

    private Title CreateTitle()
    {
        // Create instance of title            
        Title title = new Title();

        // Set title using variable
        String chartTitle = "Custom Chart Result";
        title.Text = chartTitle;

        // Set font style
        title.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 14F, FontStyle.Bold);
        title.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);

        return title;
    }

    private Legend CreateLegend()
    {
        //Initializes a new instance of the Legend class.
        Legend legend = new Legend();

        // show/hide legend
        legend.Enabled = true;

        //set legend content font style , colour 
        legend.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 14F, FontStyle.Bold);
        legend.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);

        // Set legend title            
        legend.Title = "Legend";

        return legend;
    }


    private ChartArea CreateChartArea()
    {
        // Initializes a new instance of the ChartArea class called chartArea.
        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();

        // Sets name of the chart object
        chartArea.Name = "Result Chart";

        // sets the background color of the ChartArea object.
        chartArea.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

        // Show Axis labels on/off
        chartArea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        chartArea.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = true;

        // Set axis label font style
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif", 8F, FontStyle.Regular);
        chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif", 8F, FontStyle.Regular);

        // Set colour of x/y edge lines 
        chartArea.AxisY.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
        chartArea.AxisX.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);

        // Set x/y grid lines colour & set interval between lines 
        chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
        chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        return chartArea;
    }

    public Series CreateSeries()
    {
        Series seriesDetail = new Series();
        // adjust legend data name
        seriesDetail.Name = "Result!";

        seriesDetail.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
        // Sets Colour of Bar/Segments/Data ect 
        seriesDetail.Color = Color.FromArgb(198, 99, 99);

        // Set the Chart Type
        seriesDetail.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        // NO IDEA ATM
        seriesDetail.BorderWidth = 1;


        // Adjust the Chart Series values used for X + Y
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(graphselected))
        {
            switch(graphselected)
            {
                case "1":
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Cats", 1);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Dogs", 3);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Bats", 5);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Mouse", 2);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Cats", 10);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Dogs", 30);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Bats", 50);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Mouse", 20);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Cats", 100);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Dogs", 300);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Bats", 500);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Mouse", 200);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Cats", 1000);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Dogs", 3000);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Bats", 5000);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("Mouse", 2000);
                    break;
                default:
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("H", 1);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("E", 5);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("L", 5);
                    seriesDetail.Points.AddXY("P", 1);
                    break;

            }
        }


            //sets the name of the ChartArea object used to plot the data series
            seriesDetail.ChartArea = "Result Chart";
            return seriesDetail;

    }



    // GET: GraphDropdownModels/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel = db.GraphNames.Find(id);
        if (graphDropdownModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(graphDropdownModel);
    }

    // GET: GraphDropdownModels/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: GraphDropdownModels/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "GraphID,GraphName")] GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.GraphNames.Add(graphDropdownModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(graphDropdownModel);
    }

    // GET: GraphDropdownModels/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel = db.GraphNames.Find(id);
        if (graphDropdownModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(graphDropdownModel);
    }

    // POST: GraphDropdownModels/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "GraphID,GraphName")] GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(graphDropdownModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(graphDropdownModel);
    }

    // GET: GraphDropdownModels/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel = db.GraphNames.Find(id);
        if (graphDropdownModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(graphDropdownModel);
    }

    // POST: GraphDropdownModels/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        GraphDropdownModel graphDropdownModel = db.GraphNames.Find(id);
        db.GraphNames.Remove(graphDropdownModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the solution to my problem.

The issue was the variable, public string graphselected; after adding a watch on the variable i could see the value was being dropped as the code ran, so the value was always null. All that was needed was to add the word "static" to ensure the variable would not get dropped.

Fix : public static string graphselected;